# Why is cassandra not reading data from the local node?

Tags: cassandra

I'm running a three-node cassandra cluster. I created a table with the following configuration:

```
cassandra@cqlsh> describe docstore;

CREATE KEYSPACE docstore WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;

CREATE TABLE docstore.docs (
    docid uuid PRIMARY KEY
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = 'NONE';
```

I traced a read command via CQL, and I see that a message is being sent from the coordinator node to another node:

```
                                                                                                                                                                                    Execute CQL3 query | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.438000 | 10.155.32.67 |              0 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                 Parsing select * from docstore.docs where docId = f8e682f0-b4d0-9b83-bcdb-4a182453d9c9; [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.438000 | 10.155.32.67 |             97 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                                     Preparing statement [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.438000 | 10.155.32.67 |            182 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                               Executing single-partition query on roles [ReadStage-3] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.438000 | 10.155.32.67 |            411 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                                            Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-3] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.438000 | 10.155.32.67 |            425 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                               Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [ReadStage-3] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.438000 | 10.155.32.67 |            443 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1 [ReadStage-3] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.438001 | 10.155.32.67 |            467 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                               Merged data from memtables and 1 sstables [ReadStage-3] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.438001 | 10.155.32.67 |            533 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                                  Read 1 live rows and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-3] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.438001 | 10.155.32.67 |            554 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                               Executing single-partition query on roles [ReadStage-2] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.438001 | 10.155.32.67 |            763 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                                            Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-2] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.438001 | 10.155.32.67 |            776 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                               Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [ReadStage-2] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.438001 | 10.155.32.67 |            785 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1 [ReadStage-2] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.438001 | 10.155.32.67 |            800 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                               Merged data from memtables and 1 sstables [ReadStage-2] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.439000 | 10.155.32.67 |            832 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                                  Read 1 live rows and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-2] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.439000 | 10.155.32.67 |            847 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                         reading data from /10.155.32.56 [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.439000 | 10.155.32.67 |            956 | 10.155.32.56
 Sending READ message to cassandra-0.cassandra-headless.default.svc.cluster.local/10.155.32.56 [MessagingService-Outgoing-cassandra-0.cassandra-headless.default.svc.cluster.local/10.155.32.56-Small] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.439000 | 10.155.32.67 |           1015 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                        REQUEST_RESPONSE message received from /10.155.32.56 [MessagingService-Incoming-/10.155.32.56] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.440000 | 10.155.32.67 |           1957 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                       Processing response from /10.155.32.56 [RequestResponseStage-4] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.440000 | 10.155.32.67 |           1987 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                    READ message received from /10.155.32.67 [MessagingService-Incoming-/10.155.32.67] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.451000 | 10.155.32.56 |              4 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                                Executing single-partition query on docs [ReadStage-3] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.451000 | 10.155.32.56 |            115 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                                            Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-3] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.451000 | 10.155.32.56 |            135 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                                               Merging memtable contents [ReadStage-3] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.451000 | 10.155.32.56 |            150 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1 [ReadStage-3] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.452000 | 10.155.32.56 |            258 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                                  Read 1 live rows and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-3] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.452000 | 10.155.32.56 |            368 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                                     Enqueuing response to /10.155.32.67 [ReadStage-3] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.452000 | 10.155.32.56 |            552 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                     Sending REQUEST_RESPONSE message to /10.155.32.67 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/10.155.32.67-Small] | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.452000 | 10.155.32.56 |            664 | 10.155.32.56
                                                                                                                                                                                      Request complete | 2022-12-21 22:06:53.440087 | 10.155.32.67 |           2087 | 10.155.32.56
```

Why is a request being sent from the coordinator node to another node, considering the coordinator node contains the data that's being requested? I have a replication factor of 3 on a three-node cluster, so every node contains all the data.

Comment: Your CQL Trace is hard to read. I'd suggest to add a ">" bracket in front of the first line of the traced output and remove the ``` triple-back-tick lines at the top and the bottom of that output

Answer (score 1):

What consistency level do you use for your read? If it's higher than ONE/LOCAL_ONE then the coordinator will request from another node to ensure consistency.  I'd try running 'consistency LOCAL_ONE;' before the query with the same trace output to see if it changes.

Comment: I appreciate the response Paul! The consistency level was set to ONE previously. I tried setting it to LOCAL_ONE and I'm seeing the same behavior.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, the data is sometimes read from the coordinator node. But most of the time it sends a request to another node.

Comment: I don't believe there is any method for controlling which node the coordinator ultimately pulls from. Using something like the token aware driver policy would probably be the closest you could get.  Just to be sure, you didn't manually specify initial_token values or anything like that when bootstrapping the nodes correct? Do all nodes belong to the same rack?

Comment: No, I'm using the bitnami cassandra helm charts to deploy it to my kubernetes cluster. I haven't modified any of the default settings. Yes, all nodes belong to the same rack.